# Get asana tasks in project with assignee information

Tags: api, asana

I am trying to retrieve asana tasks within a project. I would like to retrieve assignee information in the same query. I tried this query and got assignee id:

```
curl -u <key>: "https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/<project-id>/tasks?opt_fields=name,created_at,assignee
```

I want get assignee name. So I include "opt_expand=assignee":

```
curl -u <key>: "https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/<project-id>/tasks?opt_fields=name,created_at,assignee&opt_expand=assignee
```

I still don't get assignee name. What's the way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(I work at Asana)

The interplay between `opt_fields` and `opt_expand` is actually a bit complicated, we should clarify in the documentation. The latter ends up superseded by - not additive with - the former.

The best way to achieve what you want would be to NOT use `opt_expand` and to add `assignee.name` to the list of fields in `opt_fields`.

Comment: Thanks, and please update the docs.  They are brutally confusing on this issue.