# Asana API not returning Assignee information when requested using opt_fields

Tags: api, asana

I wish to retrieve tasks (and additional info) in a particular project. Assignee info is not being retrieved.

I made the following api call:

> https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks?project=projectidhidden&opt_fields=name,created_at,assignee,assignee.name,assignee.id

which after urlencoding looks like this:

> https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks?project=projectidhidden&opt_fields=name%2Ccreated_at%2Cassignee%2Cassignee.name%2Cassignee.id

The api returned task name and created_at information but assignee information was not returned.

Following link specifically mentions assignee information was returned successfully:
[Get asana tasks in project with assignee information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095933/get-asana-tasks-in-project-with-assignee-information?answertab=active#tab-top)

How do I retrieve assignee information for each task without making additional API calls?

Thanks.

Update:
I had missed mentioning the project id while typing out the above urls. Made the correction; I'm passing the project id too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I work at Asana)

Are you sure this is the exact request you are making? It doesn't have a "project" or "assignee" parameter to filter the tasks so this should return an error.

Also, be sure that that the tasks being returned actually have assignees. Tasks that have no assignee will return `assignee: null`, and your request for `assignee.name` will have no effect on that task since it has no assignee.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I'm passing the project id, missed typing that out above. I was reading the data incorrectly.